# Fill a ace:comboBox value from controller bean

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I want to auto-complete the value of my `ace:comboBox` when it has only one selectItem.

This is my JSF combo:

```
<ace:comboBox id="target" value="#{controller.filters.target}" 
            styleClass="combo-read-only" rendered="#{true}">

        <f:selectItems value="#{controller.targets}" />

</ace:comboBox>
```

So in my controller I have:

```
@PostConstruct
@Override
protected void init() {
       /* code in which I populate my targets list */
       if(targets.size() == 1) {
              String target = targets.get(0);
              getFilters().setTarget(target);
       }
```

targets is a list of `javax.faces.model.SelectItem`.

But when I load my JSF, the comboBox does not contain the auto-complete value, but in the `selectedItems` there's only one item.

I am not understanding what is wrong in my code.

Comment: Could you clarify in which method of your controller you have this code?

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski yes, I have this code in my PostConstruct init method, in which I retrieve my items from an array, that I filter for some conditions

Comment: Hi, please read [mcve]! it is **impossible** to answer your question. (if you want to know why in more detail, read http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ (I did not downvote yet, but two upvotes are suspicious (collegues?))

Comment: @Kukeltje have upvotes on my stackoverflow question is not my reason for living.
I have edited my question. If something is not clear, you can ask me what I'm missing.

Comment: I did... see mij previous comment about a [mcve]